# Изменить значение извлеченных данных yii2

Tags: yii2

Данные извлекаются из нескольких таблиц. Нужно изменить значение одного поля, делаю так

```
public function afterFind() {
    $this->id = 1;
}
```

но в результате значение не изменяется, а вставляется еще одно, как-то так:

```
array(14) {
  [0]=>
  object(app\models\Details)#75 (9) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(11) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(10)
      ["name"]=>
      string(8) "Иван"
      ...
```

Comment: Покажите структуру таблиц, из которых берутся данные и код как вы извлекаете данные из этих таблиц

Comment: @Peresada извлекаю так Clients::find()->with('orders')->all();
В таблице Clients есть поля id, name, email, password
После извлечения данных для отображения нужно изменить значение одного из полей

Comment: @Peresada так не получается. Связи установлены

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только что проверил в своем приложении, у меня все работает. Вот конкретно, что и где у меня прописано:

**class Order extends ActiveRecord**

```
public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
    }

public function afterFind() {
        $this->id = 'Order';
    }
```

**class User extends ActiveRecord**

```
public function getOrders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
    }
public function afterFind() {
        $this->id = 'User';
    }
```

**Контроллер**

```
public function actionIndex()
    {

        $test = User::find()->with('orders')->all();
        foreach ($test as $t) {
            echo $t->id;
            echo $t->orders[0]->id;
        }
        // вывело UserOrderUserOrderUserOrder то есть все работает правильно
        return $this->render('index');
    }
```

СРавнивайте Ваш код с моим, и проверяйте, что не так